# Using same name for id and classname of an element?

Tags: html, css

I have some s in my webpage, is there anything wrong with sometimes using the same name as the classname and id? Something like:

```
<div id='foo' class='foo'>hello</div>
```

just wondering -

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using identical IDs and class names will not give you any problems as long as the `id` attribute is unique.

Comment: Agreed, you can have in your css `div#foo.foo` if you really wanted to

Comment: I could not find it but went on for stupid answer without reference. I second you now though. +1